# Nuget 3.5 strips off leading zeros when it packs a package

Tags: nuget-package

In v3.5 the behaviour has changed so that when it packs a package it will strip off leading zeros. This is not the behaviour we want. I hope it can be fixed in v3.6.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question...

Answer (score 6):

As explained on the [Package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning) page there was a breaking change introduced for NuGet 3.4 and later which entails "normalization" of the version numbers:

> When obtaining packages from a repository during install, reinstall, or restore operations, NuGet 3.4+ treats version numbers as follows:
>
> Leading zeroes are removed from version numbers:
>
> ```
> 1.00 is treated as 1.0
> 1.01.1 is treated as 1.1.1
> 1.00.0.1 is treated as 1.0.0.1
> ```
>
> A zero in the fourth part of the version number will be omitted

```
  1.0.0.0 is treated as 1.0.0
  1.0.01.0 is treated as 1.0.1
```

> This normalization does not affect the version numbers in the packages themselves; it affects only how NuGet matches versions when resolving dependencies.

The only workaround I am aware of is to use version 3.3.0 of nuget from [download page](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).