# Nuget package restore is skipping revision part of version number if it is zero

Tags: asp.net, .net, nuget-package-restore

I have a package config file for a project this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Stylesoft.Common.Dev" version="1.0.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

And the package dll is referenced like this in csproj file

```
<Reference Include="Stylesoft.Common.Dev, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\SharedPackages\Stylesoft.Common.Dev.1.0.1.0\lib\net40\Stylesoft.Common.Dev.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Earlier this used to work because nuget used to restore the package in this folder `Stylesoft.Common.Dev.1.0.1.0` but I don't know what was changed but now nuget skip the revision number of version, now it creates folder with name `Stylesoft.Common.Dev.1.0.1` skipping last zero and so I get compile error, because the project tries to check dll in this path

```
..\..\..\..\..\SharedPackages\Stylesoft.Common.Dev.1.0.1.0\lib\net40\Stylesoft.Common.Dev.dll
```

I am not able to figure out what was changed and how to make it restore package in the same folder structure as earlier

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuget 3.5 strips off leading zeros when it packs a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377489/nuget-3-5-strips-off-leading-zeros-when-it-packs-a-package)

Comment: tl;dr from the question I linked to: from NuGet 3.4, if the revision number is zero, NuGet will omit it. This is presumably because NuGet is attempting to align with SemVer, which only uses the first 3 parts of the version. You should simply need to remove and re-add that package reference.

Answer (score -1):

I was suffering the same problem. The cause will either be that the nuget.exe version has been updated and now downloading packages excluding the revision in the path, or that a change has occurred where the packages are hosted. Not sure which for myself as this happened when migrating source from TFS to Azure DevOps. So the build pipeline is different and the packages are on a new feed.

I feel the best solution is to make the projects in Visual Studio work locally the same way the server build expects them to. So as it is looking for packages in folders excluding the revision number in their name, that's where they should be.

So the fix is to reinstall the packages using the same feed and nuget client. The visual studio package manager should install the packages to the correct location. So you can either ensure that you have the correct versions, or just hope it will be ok and continue with the following:

1. Delete all of the packages from the packages folder (hopefully all your projects use the same folder otherwise this may be laborious).
2. Clear your nuget package cache from visual studio (there's a button to do this under Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager)
3. In visual studio, open the nuget package manager console.
4. Run 'Update-Package -reinstall'

It may take some time depending on how many packages and projects you have, but this will hopefully ensure your project reference hint paths will match the packages' installed locations.